Displaying links in a PhP SQL Management website as hyperlinks, based on conditions
I wrote a database and imported it to PhpMyAdmin, and using old uni resources, I also have an SQL Database Management Website, and I have it loaded into Wampserver.
My database has the aim of displaying artists I like, and their music.
One of the tables is artistinfo, this table displays the artist name, country, social media link, and a streaming platform link.
I want the links in this table, to appear as hyperlinks with the text saying what social media and streaming platform the link is for, and I also want when I click the link, it takes me to a new blank tab in my web browser.
When you enter a social media or streaming link, there are so many to choose from. Some of the artists I like, either don't have Twitter or Instagram, which is the ones I enter in my database.
So, I want the hyperlink display text that appears to be conditional.
I want it so if the link contains twitter.com, the hyperlink text will say Twitter, and you click the link and it will open a new blank tab to the artists twitter page.
If the link contains instagram.com, I want the hyperlink to say Instagram.
Here is the code in one the artist index code for connecting to the database and selecting and displaying the data from my database.

<?php
    // attempt to connect to the DB
    $dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dylansmusicdatabase");
    if ($dbconn->connect_error > 0) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . $dbconn->connect_error);
        exit(); // you should redirect to some form of error page !!!!
    }
 
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM artistinfo");
    $datatable = "<table id='artistinfo' class='table table-bordered table-striped' style='width:100%'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th></th>       
                    <th>ArtistName</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>SocialMedia</th>
                    <th>Music</th>
                    <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
            $datatable.= "<tr>";
            $datatable.= "<td><a href=update.php?artistid=".$row['ArtistID'].">Edit</a></td>";
            $datatable.= "<td>" . $row['ArtistName'] . "</td>";
            $datatable.= "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
            $datatable.= "<td>" . $row['Social_Media'] . "</td>";
            $datatable.= "<td>" . $row['Music_Streaming'] . "</td>";
            $datatable.= "<td><a href=delete.php?ArtistID=".$row['ArtistName'].">Delete</a></td>";      
            $datatable.= "</tr>";
       }

    $datatable.= "</tbody></table>";

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($dbconn);
 ?>


Okay, and which part of this are you struggling with? How do I check if a string contains a specific word? might be a starting point.

I'm struggling with actually making the social_media and streaming_platform to be hyperlinks, and for them to display specific text based on what the link contains.
Obviously, I know how to do a hyperlink in websites, but I have never done it before with SQL and PHP. And I do not know how to do it. And I'm struggling with trying to figure out how to do it. I am also awful at explaining things, I'm sorry.

Focus on one thing at a time. Create the hyperlinks first, while keeping the link text static. Once you got that working, you can move on to making the link text dynamic, based on where it actually links to.

You seem to be missing quotes around your a link hrefs.  Ex: <a href="xxxxx"> or 


Used a custom PHP function, getSocialMediaPlatform(), to identify the social media platform from the link by mapping specific URL substrings to their respective platform names.
Utilized the <a> tag with the target="_blank" attribute to create hyperlinks. This ensures that when the user clicks the link, it opens in a new blank page.

I also corrected a detail: the delete button should reference the artist's ID instead of their name.
Below is the complete and updated code. You can modify it further according to your needs:
<table id='artistinfo' class='table table-bordered table-striped' style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>ArtistName</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>SocialMedia</th>
            <th>Music</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        function getSocialMediaPlatform($url)
        {
            $platforms = [
                'twitter.com' => 'Twitter',
                'x.com' => 'Twitter',
                'instagram.com' => 'Instagram',
                'facebook.com' => 'Facebook',
                'linkedin.com' => 'LinkedIn'
            ];

            foreach ($platforms as $key => $platform) {
                if (strpos($url, $key) !== false) {
                    return $platform;
                }
            }

            return 'Social Media';
        }

        $dbconn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dylansmusicdatabase");
        if ($dbconn->connect_error > 0) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . $dbconn->connect_error);
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM artistinfo");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $artist_id = $row['ArtistID'];
            $artist_name = $row['ArtistName'];
            $country = $row['Country'];
            $social_media_link = $row['Social_Media'];
            $music_streaming_link = $row['Music_Streaming'];
            $platform_name = getSocialMediaPlatform($social_media_link);
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="update.php?artistid=<?php echo $artist_id; ?>">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $artist_name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $country; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $social_media_link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $platform_name; ?></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo $music_streaming_link; ?>" target="_blank">Open</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="delete.php?ArtistID=<?php echo $artist_id; ?>">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }

        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php
//close connection
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>

